# External access to home Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, webrick

My home server is running on Raspberry Pi with Rasbian (Debian for ARM)
There rails server is running: `rvmsudo rails s -b ${LOCAL_IP} -p 80`

It works perfectly fine to access from local machines, but it is not working when I am trying to access from outside of my local network

It should not be a router problem as I can easily access that server over ssh (both :22 and :80 are open in router preferences)

Comment: try `rvmsudo rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80`

Comment: can you ssh into your pi from outside your local network?

Comment: @Yule Yes, there was no problems with ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access http via your local network ip, then it can be issue with router, look to port forwarding settings of DMZ.

BTW, router can use 80 port for its own purposes, like web interface. Try to bind to 8080 port for example.

As an alternative to share 80 port via internet you can use https://ngrok.com/

It allows you to share localhost http to anyone.

Comment: Actually main problem was related to accessing my public IP from my local network - thats wont work due router limitations.